# Remove LF from a specific column using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file which contains data separated by `|`.

Example: (Input)

```
a|b|c|d`LF`
D|e
a1|b1|c1|d1`LF`
d2|e1\n
```

Output: (Removed `LF` from 4th column)

```
a|b|c|dD|e
a1|b1|c1|d1d2|e1\n
```

I want to remove `LF` from a particular column using `sed`.  Is it possible to delete `LF` characters from a particular column.

Comment: Yes, actual LF characters. Means data contains new lines

Comment: Feels like your format is somewhat broken, the other \n are they literal or `LF` too?

Comment: What is the difference between "LF" and "\n"? Is this really a text file, or is it some kind of spreadsheet file in which cells may contain embedded newlines?

Comment: @bac0n yes, these are `LF `

Comment: so it feels like you are trying to concat columns that are four columns  wide

Comment: @steeldriver - I need to replace `LF` characters from 4th column. I got confused and added `\n` previously.

Comment: @αғsнιη I've edited the question. I need to remove `LF` characters from a particular column.

Comment: oh yes sorry, I missed that as well. I've fixed that.

Comment: I've added backticks to denote that there is a LF character means Line Feed which is not visible directly. \n is in the data. The input contains both LF and \n. I need to replace the LF from the 4th column.

Comment: if you do `od -c inputfile` what character that shows?

Answer (score 0):

You mean to do something like:

```Awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "|"; OFS = "|"; i=0 }
{
    a[i]=(a[i] ? 
        sprintf("%s%s\n", a[i], $0) : sprintf("%s", $0))

    if(NF!=4) {
        ++i
    }
}
END {
    for(e in a) {
        printf("%s", a[e])
    }
}
```

And you run it with `-f`:

```
awk -f script.awk text.txt
```

Comment: I've made some edits for LF. Can you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your input file was made on Windows platform having CR (Carriage Return) line ending;

if you do `cat -e filename.txt` you will see something similar as following (note the `^M` character):

```
a|b|c|d^M$
D|e$
a1|b1|c1|d1^M$
d2|e1\n$
```

for that, you can do:

```
CR=$'\r' ; sed -E ":a /${CR}$/ { N; s/\n//; ta; }; s/${CR}//g;" infile.txt
a|b|c|dD|e
a1|b1|c1|d1d2|e1\n
```

---

Let `printf` generate the carriage return character with `CR=$(printf %s '\r')` if your shell doesn't recognize [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) syntax like `$'\r'`.